# How to programatically authenticate user after changing password? Form-based authentication using j_security_check was used to login

Tags: java, authentication

How can I programatically authenticate user after changing password? Form-based authentication using j_security_check was used to login. After changing the password, the user is redirected to the Home page (which is what is required) but when the screen is submitted or a link/button is clicked, the user is redirected back to the login page. I think that is because the password being used to authenticate on the background is still the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the `HttpServletRequest` (here is an example in JSF), you can call `login()` from there.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.login(username, password);
```

Bonus information:  To log the current user out, you can call `invalidate()` on the `HttpSession`:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
session.invalidate();
```